# Can benzene undergo Diels–Alder reactions?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, pericyclic

I was reading about the Diels–Alder reaction and wondered that since benzene also consists of two conjugated double bonds, then should it also undergo Diels–Alder reactions? If not, then why not?

Comment: The properties of benzene are *very* different to the hypothetical 1,3,5 cyclohexatriene that you seek to compare it to.

Comment: With that said, some benzene lookalikes are amazing Diels-Alder substrates, e.g. triazines and tetrazines. Actually, I've covered this topic before (specifically focusing on benzenes): https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/77049/16683 The question isn't a duplicate, though.